# Populate data in mongoose on collections(generated by strapi.io)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, strapi

I have 3 collections in mongodb generated by strapi.io, I want customize query populate data by mongoose in my project. But i cannot populate data like strapi result.

Category collection:

```
{
     _id: "5d10a731c5077836540bebf0",
     posts: [
     "5d10a6fbc5077836540bebed",
     "5d10af45c5077836540bebf1"
     ],
     name: "Support",
     ids: "support",
     keywords: "support",
     des: "support des",
     createdAt: "2019-06-24T10:34:25.383Z",
     updatedAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.475Z",
     __v: 0,
     id: "5d10a731c5077836540bebf0"
}
```

Post collection:

```
{
    _id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf1",
    ids: "test",
    title: "this is test",
    des: "test",
    keywords: "test",
    body: "testtesttesttesttest",
    createdAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.467Z",
    updatedAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.477Z",
    __v: 0,
    id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf1"
}
```

FileUpload collection:

```
{
    _id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf2",
    name: "THUMBNAIL.png",
    sha256: "0bP9PI3R_ygF07cLhg5U-syLeVCz4ZbBrwZZi2OtPL4",
    hash: "9f4e8bbd13b94f2baa3d26b335124717",
    ext: ".png",
    mime: "image/png",
    size: "297.33",
    url: "/uploads/9f4e8bbd13b94f2baa3d26b335124717.png",
    provider: "local",
    related: 
    [
        {
        _id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf3",
        ref: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf1",
        kind: "Post",
        field: "pic"
        }
    ],
    createdAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.501Z",
    updatedAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.505Z",
    __v: 0,
    id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf2"
}
```

I can populate "posts" on Category model with

```
Cat.find().populate({path: 'posts',model: 'Post'})
```

But I can not populate "categories" and "pic" on Post model.

How can I populate "categories" and "pic" like this result of strapi:

```
{
    _id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf1",
    ids: "test",
    title: "this is test",
    des: "test",
    keywords: "test",
    body: "testtesttesttesttest",
    createdAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.467Z",
    updatedAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.477Z",
    __v: 0,
    id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf1",
    pic: {
        _id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf2",
        name: "THUMBNAIL.png",
        sha256: "0bP9PI3R_ygF07cLhg5U-syLeVCz4ZbBrwZZi2OtPL4",
        hash: "9f4e8bbd13b94f2baa3d26b335124717",
        ext: ".png",
        mime: "image/png",
        size: "297.33",
        url: "/uploads/9f4e8bbd13b94f2baa3d26b335124717.png",
        provider: "local",
        related: [
            "5d10af45c5077836540bebf1"
        ],
        createdAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.501Z",
        updatedAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.505Z",
        __v: 0,
        id: "5d10af45c5077836540bebf2"
    },
    categories: 
    [
        {
            posts: [
                "5d10a6fbc5077836540bebed",
                "5d10af45c5077836540bebf1"
            ],
            _id: "5d10a731c5077836540bebf0",
            name: "Support",
            ids: "support",
            keywords: "support",
            des: "support des",
            createdAt: "2019-06-24T10:34:25.383Z",
            updatedAt: "2019-06-24T11:08:53.475Z",
            __v: 0,
            id: "5d10a731c5077836540bebf0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the database you use ? And what is your Strapi version please ?

Answer (score -1):

you have to create another collection inside the post. as like you have an independent collection then you can populate. for example :

Post: {body: ,title: ,Image : { image: {name : , etc }}}

this can be a collection inside collection. the above code is not correct you have to mention your own fields.